# Loop breaking even if there is more data to run through the array's elements

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three tables all of them containing data about different partners for the company, there is a Hierarchy already in place, Sales Partners are under Holiday Partners and these, in turn, are under Super Partners, all of this data is already in the database, now I need to show the business carried forward by the sales partner on the holiday partner's dashboard (of the sales partners under him) and same for the superpartners.

The problem is that I am not able to retrieve the data about the next subsequent level of the hierarchy,  like, on the dash of holiday partners, I am only able to display the data about the holiday partners and not the sales partners under him.

Already tried removing the foreach loop, as I know it unnecessarily increases complexity, tried keep if-elseif condition to no avail.

case "Holiday Partner":

```
  //2nd level, need holiday as well as sales partners
  $case = 2;
   //holiday partner data, i.e getting to know which holiday partner we're talking about
  $sql2 = "SELECT sno, district, state FROM holidaypartners WHERE name = '$userid'";
  $res = $conn->query($sql2);
   if ($res->num_rows)
   {
     if($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
      $sno = $row["sno"];
      $district = $row["district"];
      $state = $row["state"];
     }
   }
   echo"$sno - "; //this is getting printed
   //got sno of holiday partner
    $sql1= "SELECT * FROM agent_form_data
             WHERE sales_partner_name ='".$sno."' and formstatus = 'pending'";
    $res = $conn->query($sql1);
    //check for forms filled by the holiday partner himself
    if ($res->num_rows){
       while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
         $datesent =date_create($row["datesent"]);
         $datesent =date_format($datesent,"d-M-Y");
        echo "<tr>
                <td>GHRN".(5000+(int)$row["ref_num"])."</td>
                <td>".$row["cust_firstname"]." ".$row["cust_lastname"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["holi_dest"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["date_of_travel"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["return_date_of_travel"]."</td>
                <td>".$row["duration"]."</td>
                <td>".$datesent."</td>
                </tr>";
        }
    }
     //sales partner data
    $sql = "SELECT sno FROM salespartners WHERE holiday_partner_sno = '$sno'";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($res->num_rows){
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
              $nums = array_values($row); //converting into a normal array for the foreach loop
              foreach($nums as $val){
                echo "$val "; //here only the first value is getting printed, suppose there are four sales partners under him, 6001,6002,6003,6004, now on execution, it prints only 6001, if there is no data to show it simply exits *all* the loops.

                $sql2= "SELECT * FROM agent_form_data
                WHERE sales_partner_name ='".$val."' and formstatus = 'pending'";//on the other hand, if I remove the SQL part, all the ids under this holiday partner are getting printed, which proves that the array has it but SQL for some reason isn't checking all of the members of the array
                $res = $conn->query($sql2);
                if($res->num_rows){
                  echo"Hi!";
                  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo $row["ref_num"];
                    $datesent =date_create($row["datesent"]);
                    $datesent =date_format($datesent,"d-M-Y");
                    echo "<tr>
                        <td>GHRN".(5000+(int)$row["ref_num"])."</td>
                        <td>".$row["cust_firstname"]." ".$row["cust_lastname"]."</td>
                        <td>".$row["holi_dest"]."</td>
                        <td>".$row["date_of_travel"]."</td>
                        <td>".$row["return_date_of_travel"]."</td>
                        <td>".$row["duration"]."</td>
                        <td>".$datesent."</td>
                        </tr>";
                  }
              }
              else{
                echo "No Data";
              }

              }
    }
   }
  break;
```

I am not getting any errors as such, as there are no syntactical blemishes, however, I should be able to cycle through all the elements (ids of the partners under a holiday partner) for the required result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your code more cleanly. You name all your queries and results similarly resulting to overwrites.

I tried to write your query more cleanly so that you will get the idea. I cannot test since I don't have the db but this should be enough to get you going.

```
$query_salespartners = "SELECT sno FROM salespartners WHERE holiday_partner_sno = '$sno'";
$res_salespartners = $conn->query($query_salespartners);
if ($res_salespartners->num_rows) {
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
  $val = $row['sno'];
  echo "$val "; //here only the first value is getting printed, suppose there are four sales partners under him, 6001,6002,6003,6004, now on execution, it prints only 6001, if there is no data to show it simply exits *all* the loops.

  $query_sales= "SELECT * FROM agent_form_data
  WHERE sales_partner_name ='".$val."' and formstatus = 'pending'";//on the other hand, if I remove the SQL part, all the ids under this holiday partner are getting printed, which proves that the array has it but SQL for some reason isn't checking all of the members of the array
  $res_sales = $conn->query($query_sales);
  if($res_sales->num_rows){
    echo"Hi!";
    while($row_sales = $res_sales->fetch_assoc()){
      echo $row_sales["ref_num"];
      $datesent =date_create($row_sales["datesent"]);
      $datesent =date_format($datesent,"d-M-Y");
      echo "<tr>
          <td>GHRN".(5000+(int)$row_sales["ref_num"])."</td>
          <td>".$row_sales["cust_firstname"]." ".$row_sales["cust_lastname"]."</td>
          <td>".$row_sales["holi_dest"]."</td>
          <td>".$row_sales["date_of_travel"]."</td>
          <td>".$row_sales["return_date_of_travel"]."</td>
          <td>".$row_sales["duration"]."</td>
          <td>".$datesent."</td>
          </tr>";
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Not working, renamed it to $sql_sales, getting the same result after execution.

Comment: I've updated my answer trying to rewrite part of the code (though untested). I hope this helps.

Comment: I renamed all my SQL queries after your initial response for the shown case uniquely to avoid such a situation,  doesn't help. Thanks anyways!

Comment: In my update I also removed the foreach($nums as $val){} loop and instead took $val = $row['sno']; directly. Try that as well.

Comment: Renamed almost all the variables, it worked! Thank you so much!